# Is there a way to securely transmit data from Windows Mobile 6.5 over the Internet?

Tags: ssl, ssh, windows-mobile, sftp

I have an application in C++ that needs to transmit data securely via web services to our web server.

VPN was the first choice, but out network administrator informs us that we will not support the IPSEC protocols available on Windows Mobile.

Currently we have tried implementing a SSL connection, but found we don't have the libraries for that.

Alternatively, we have been trying [PocketPutty](http://www.pocketputty.net/) to create a SSH tunnel, but that only has a GUI interface, and we're not sure how to get that to work via programming code.

Thank you

Comment: SSL should work just fine.  What is it you think you need that you don't have for SSL?

Comment: I'm not the primary developer, but from what I understand the C++ API for development does not support SSL and they can't get libraries to recompile it to do that. The developer wrote a python script to handle the data interactions, but that too doesn't do SSL.

Comment: I'm hoping the missing API's is incorrect, and we just can't find them.

Comment: Have you read [Securing Communications with SSL and the .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738067.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) supports Windows CE.

[SSL 2.0 has been supported since at least CE 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886618.aspx).

[SecureBlackBox is also supported](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-ssl.php).